# PATH Linux Para Windows

Tags: linux, shell-script

De casusalidad saben como generar un path para buscar una carpeta ya que yo tengo mi cassandra db instalado pero quiero que la encuentre este donde este

Este solo Funciona para linux

```
PATH = $PATH:/bin/cqlsh
```

Necesito saber si en mi shell script puedo generar un path pero para windows de alguna manera y encontrar mi cassandra cql este donde este

lo que necesito es esto

ruta = C:/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/bin/cqlsh este no

ruta = ../apache-cassandra-3.11.4/bin/clqsh <----- este path si pero QUITANDO c para que lo identifique el folder este donde este

```
$ruta EJECUCION DEL QUERY
```

Comment: Si estas en Linux ejecuta en el terminal "which cassandra" esto te devolverá la ruta, luego agregarla a tu path.

Comment: no estoy en linux si no en windows

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que necesitás es usar el where para obtener el path completo de un .exe en específico instalado en tu sistema, en mi caso por ejemplo python:

```
C:\Users\frocc>where python.exe
C:\Users\frocc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Si seguis con dudas, no dudes en consultar la documentación:

```
C:\Users\frocc>where /?
```